# Remove anchor tag from a particular subcategory in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I want to disable the anchor tag of two subcategories. I used a free extension for topmenu. The code for subcategory menu is:

```
public function drawMenuItem($children, $level = 1)
    {
        $html = '<div class="itemMenu level' . $level . '">';
        $keyCurrent = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if (is_object($child) && $child->getIsActive()) {
                // --- class for active category ---
                $active = '';
                if ($this->isCategoryActive($child)) {
                    $active = ' actParent';
                    if ($child->getId() == $keyCurrent) $active = ' act';
                }
                // --- format category name ---
                $name = $this->escapeHtml($child->getName());
                if (Mage::getStoreConfig('custom_menu/general/non_breaking_space')) $name = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $name);
                $html.= '<a class="itemMenuName level' . $level . $active . '" href="' . $this->getCategoryUrl($child) . '"><span>' . $name . '</span></a>';
                $activeChildren = $this->_getActiveChildren($child, $level);
                if (count($activeChildren) > 0) {
                    $html.= '<div class="itemSubMenu level' . $level . '">';
                    $html.= $this->drawMenuItem($activeChildren, $level + 1);
                    $html.= '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
        $html.= '</div>';
        return $html;
    }
```

I tried to disable the two subcategories. But it didn't work. How can I give proper condition to disable particular two subcategories link?

Comment: if it's only 2 sub cats why don't you just do it by using JS. Add an id to each item menu, target it and remove the href $("a").removeAttr("href");

Comment: submenu are coming dynamically then how can i add an id for particular two subcategory. It is for all as you can see above code